# Replacing values within a specific group using a numeric condition

Tags: r

I have a sample dataset and code which is as follows:

```
structure(list(Variable = c(NA, "Continuous", "Cell 1", " ",  " ", " ", NA, "Cell 2", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Cell 3", NA, NA, NA,  NA, "Cell 3", NA, NA, NA, NA), Type = c(NA, NA, "Type 1", "Type 2",  "Type 3", "Type 4", "Other", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4",  "Other", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4", "Other", "Type 1",  "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4", "Other"), R = c(NA, NA, "1", "  NA",  "0.23", "0.14", "0.4", "0.4", "  NA", "0.88", "0.32", "0.17",  "1", "  NA", "0.39", "0.24", "0.84", "0.27", "  NA", "0.5", "0.27",  "0.18"), R_event = c(NA, NA, "1", "  NA", "0.67", "0.32", "0.53",  "0.81", "  NA", "0.88", "0.32", "0.36", "1", "  NA", "0.67",  "0.32", "0.84", "0.81", "  NA", "0.67", "0.32", "0.36")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))
```

I would like to search the 'R' column and replace the 'R_event' column with "0" if the value in 'R' is > 0.2. However, I would like to do this only for "Type 1" cells and not for the entire dataset. Here is the code that I tried:

```
Table <- read.csv("~/Desktop/Table.csv", stringsAsFactors = , na.strings = c("N/A", ""))

pacman::p_load(pacman, party, rio, tidyverse) 

Table$Type == "Type 1" %>% Table$R_event[Table$R>=0.2] <- 0
```

But I received the following error:

```
Error in Table$Type == "Type 1" %>% Table$R_event[Table$R >= 0.2] <- 0 : 
  could not find function "==<-"
```

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you should convert your strings like `"0.53"` to numbers, `0.53.` This can be done with `Table <- type.convert(Table)`. Then, I like a direct replacement method:

```
# direct replacement
Table[Table$R > 0.2 & Table$Type == "Type 1", "R_event"] <- 0
```

I see you had a pipe attempt with `%>%`. If you'd like to use `dplyr` for this, `mutate` is the main `dplyr` function for editing columns:

```
library(dplyr)
Table <- Table %>%
  mutate(R_event = case_when(
    R > 0.2 & Type == "Type 1" ~ 0,
    TRUE ~ R_event   # in all other cases, leave R_event as-is
  ))
```